# Array to string conversion error when using implode

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I'm confused about an error I am getting stating `Array to string conversion`

The reason I'm confused is I'm trying to do exactly that, convert an array to a string, using `implode` which according to the manual should allow me to convert my array into a string. So why am I getting an error?

var `$matches` is an array. `$error_c` is the var I want to store the string.

```
print_r($matches); // prints the array correctly
$error_c = implode(',', $matches);
echo $error_c;
```

Outputs simply `array` and gives:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in ...
```

The manual states that `implode — Join array elements with a string` so why do I get an error when I try to do it?

Edit: this is the output I get from `$matches`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => C [1] => E [2] => R [3] => R [4] => O [5] => R [6] => C [7] => O [8] => N [9] => T [10] => A [11] => C [12] => T [13] => S [14] => U [15] => P [16] => P [17] => R [18] => E [19] => S [20] => S [21] => E [22] => D ) )
```

Comment: the element of your array should be string or have `__toString` capability

Comment: You got it!  Check the answers  ;)

Comment: $matches is an array . then how can u implode the whole array $matches without exploding it, if not then u have to mention with index array like $matches[0]

Comment: This is a specific error encountered by folks sometimes when dealing with PHP - it's not broad at all.  The error is literally "array to string conversion" on the specific line of code with "implode".  I disagree with the closing of the question on this basis.  In fact, I landed on this question precisely because its wording exactly matched the error I was looking for, and the answer helped me solved it.  It's not too broad.

Answer (score 45):

You have an array of arrays... Try this:

```
$error_c = implode(',', $matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$error_c = implode(',', $matches[0]);
echo $error_c;
```

because your `array` contains `arrays` inside

Answer (score 6):

The issue is due to the fact that you are call `implode` on an `Array` which is two dimensionnal.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => C 
        [1] => E 
        [2] => R 
        [3] => R 
        [4] => O 
        [5] => R 
        [6] => C 
        [7] => O 
        [8] => N 
        [9] => T 
        [10] => A 
        // ...
    ) 
)
```

which is equivalent to

```
[["C", "E", "R", "R", "O", "R", "C", "O", "N", "..." ]]
```

What you should do before performing an implode is to flatten the array and after that you can call `implode` with the flattened array or by calling implode only with the first item in the main array which is an array.

Here is a question which provide guidance to flatten an array
[**How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

With a function which allows to flatten an array you can perform the call like this

```
implode(flatten($array_of_data), $matches);
```

No need to access the first item only, whatever number of items are in  `$matches` array the `flatten` function will return a one dimensionnal Array on which you can call `implode`

Answer (score 2):

Do that:

```
print_r($matches); // prints the array correctly
$error_c = implode(',', $matches[0]);
echo $error_c;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) for array of arrays

e.g. `implode (",", array_values($array))`

Answer (score 0):

```
#best way! fast and easy 

$string = 'whatever';
$array = (['new'],['old'],['whatever']);

    for($i = 0;$i < count($array);$i++)
    if(str_contains(json_encode($host),implode(',',$array[$i]))){
    $found = true;
    }if($found == true){echo "found";}else{echo "not found";}

# returns found
```

Answer (score -1):

To just put whatever data is in the array into a string, try this

```
function whatever_to_string($in){
    ob_start();
    print_r($in);
    return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

The 'ob_*' functions control the output buffer.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php